# Возможно ли реализовать описанный скрипт с помощью модуля vk_api Python

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

Хочу немного упростить жизнь и написать простенький скрипт для ВКонтакте. использую Python и думал использовать модуль [vk_api](https://vk-api.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). Однако, кажется, модуль мне помочь не сможет. Я достаточно долго полазил по его документации, но не смог найти нужную функциональность в модуле.

Коротко, что мне нужно:

1. Получать список альбомов одной группы (я в ней админ).
2. В одном из альбомов считывать комментарии от имени сообщества.
3. В зависимости от текста комментария, переносить фото в другой альбом (в комментарии фактически написано название альбома, в который нужно перенести).

То есть, хотелось бы автоматизировать перенос выбранных фото, которые помечены комментарием, чтобы не делать это руками.

Буду рад совету, с помощью какого модуля это получиться реализовать. Или любым другим наводкам, что почитать на эту тему.

Comment: `vk_api` может вызвать любую функцию, что есть в api vk, ищите нужную функциональность в документации к api у vk: https://vk.com/dev/methods Пример: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/415172cb7b5fecc9778851a06fbfe1a1a1c887c0/vk_api__examples/wall.post%20hello%20world.py#L33

Comment: vk_api реализует методы API, вам осталось только дописать свою логику на них. Делайте бота в своей группе, наделяйте правами и всё будет ок.